# Any recommendations for a seamless 'Robust File Copy' addition to Windows?

Tags: file-transfer

I have a new Nettop using Win7 and noticed a weakness with the Windows ‘Copy/Paste’ command. When I download typically large films using JDownloader to the C: drive, JD checks the file MD5 and tells me if there are any errors.
I then move infrequently accessed large files onto an (new, not powered unless in-use) external USB Western Digital Passport drive.

When unzipping some of the files on the USB drive (that JD had verified as ok when downloaded onto C:) 7zip reported CRC errors.

If I unzip to the local HDD C: no errors occur.  Ran the WD Lifeguard Diagnostics to check its USB cable & detailed sector check – 9hrs to check the full 1TB – Disk Passed.

For that reason I feel reasonably confident my HDDs are ok.   As a temp solution I now use 7zip to encapsulate with CRC, move my large files from C: to the ext USB drive - as that will immediately tell me if the Windows Copy/Paste operation introduced an error.  In Googling for fixes to this problem I see many references to the poor Windows quality in not reporting file copy errors, but haven't yet found articles focusing on a seamless more secure way of performing what should be a day-to-day operation.

Dropping down to MSDOS xcopy type UI is impracticable in an efficient GUI work environment, likewise a full blown 'File Compare' operation as in backup programs would be too slow.

I heard something like the free 'Teracopy' that builds itself into the Explorer file right-click menu is the right type of seamless solution and CRC checks every Copy - i.e what I am now manually doing using 7zip's encapsulate/copy/extract.

However, a number of user reviews in betanews.com last month said Teracopy was UNRELIABLE !  I prefer to keep a minimum of installed programs, and so check independent reviews before risking installing then having to uninstall something.

I have searched the net for comparative reviews of Windows GUI Tools to seamlessly integrate with Windows to “improve the reliability of the Explorer Copy/Paste function”. Apart from the Wikipedia ‘Comparison of File Managers’ which does at least have a tiny part on ‘robust file copy’, I have not found any comparative review that addresses this problem.

Clearly any 3rd party utility must have PROVEN RELIABILITY (i.e good reviews), to improve on the Windows OS, i.e not jumping from pan to fire.

Anybody know of an improvement on Teracopy ?

Comment: If your files are silently corrupting themselves in transfers between hard drives, you've got bigger problems to solve that different copying software isn't going to fix.

Comment: Any chance of a link to the reviews saying that Teracopy is unreliable?  I've been using it for a while on a drive that seemingly thinks that error correction is someone else's problem, it's an old mp3 player, and have had nothing but good experience with it.

Comment: Link is: http://fileforum.betanews.com/detail/TeraCopy/1178071395/1

Comment: Link is: http://fileforum.betanews.com/detail/TeraCopy/1178071395/1  I just googled 'betanews.com teracopy' - lucky I tested it to recall the link, as I last read it around 20 Sept.  See there are many useful user review updates, STILL saying Teracopy v. buggy - but usefully metioning alternatives which I will look into. One suggested Fastcopy  - as did 1 reply to my post here.  I tried to get response to the betanews criticism from teracopy.com, but couldn't see direct email, no reply from a form submission as yet.

Answer (score 6):

Robocopy/Richcopy usually gets my vote.

Comment: Thanks.  Before posting I read a lot in Wikipedia on their comparisons of file managers, read their bit on Robocopy & the later derived Richcopy. As I recall they both go back many years, and use the underlying MSDOS command line - the current Robocopy still so.  As result I passed them by without further reading. But if you reckon they, or with covering GUI, are as productive as the Windows Copy UI, I will google for more results on them.

Comment: Robocopy is a command-line application, but it is _not_ an MS-DOS program. It is every bit as stable and useful as any other program, and with a GUI front-end, should work just fine.

Comment: RoboCopy (Robust File Copy) its in the name and its a Microsoft program.

Answer (score 3):

I've used [RichCopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.04.utilityspotlight.aspx) before when copying large files. It's comparable to TeraCopy in terms of features, but it lacks shell integration. I've found it to be quite reliable. Alternately, I came across a [Lifehacker article](http://lifehacker.com/5280976/five-best-alternative-file-copiers) talking about other copy utilities that may be of interest, though the article's focus is on speed, not error-less copying.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Will follow that up and may get back to you.

Answer (score 3):

A  really viable option is plain old xcopy. I have a GUI front-end for xcopy available (free) at http://lorenstuff.weebly.com/  It is not a replacement or improvement on xcopy, just a GUI that simplifies the use of the program (point & click instead of command-line). The controls are:source, destination, set switches, & run.

Answer (score 2):

[Fastcopy](http://ipmsg.org/tools/fastcopy.html.en) has always been reliable (and fast) for me.

Comment: Thanks, will look that one up. May get back to you if queries

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with a USB hard drive. A few bytes per Gigabyte were being corrupted, sometimes when copying files to the USB drive, sometimes when reading back from the USB drive.
I assumed the USB drive was faulty so took it back to the shop and got it replaced. Had the same problem with the replacement.
Gave up at this point, took the HD out of the USB enclosure and installed it in a USB enclosure from a different manufacturer. This fixed the problem.
Personally, I think your WD Passport drive is simply unreliable and I would replace it with a drive that actually works, rather than try to get around the problem with a software fix.

Comment: Interesting. As I said, I ran the WD diagnostics for 9hrs - no probs (although as a related article, & also S. Gibson says, since advent of 'smart' HDDs, they can 'lie'. - makes troubleshooting harder. Since my post I moved the WD to another computer and repeated similar operation on 3 large files. No errors reported by 7zip.

Comment: Interesting your USB i/f was cause. As I said, I ran the WD diagnostics 9hrs - no probs (although as a related article, & S. Gibson says, since advent of 'smart' HDDs, they can 'lie'. - makes troubleshooting harder. Since my post I moved the WD to another computer and repeated similar operation on 3 large files. No errors reported by 7zip.  That would seem to support my earlier view, the HDDs are not the cause, and is a further indicater the Nettop USB interface, or connected busses, maybe the cause.  It is VERY annoying the Windows Copy operation does not report errors that 7zip and JD do.

Comment: @paul - If you send data to the USB device and it responds "OK", then the OS and copy utility has to assume the operation was successful. Either reading the file back and comparing it to the source file after the copy operation is done, or your CRC solution (which reads the file back as well) seem like a good safety check.

Answer (score 1):

I know that I'm late to the game here, I really like the free RoboCopy GUI program, [WinRoboCopy](http://www.upway2late.com/projects/winrobocopy/). I find it much easier to use than RichCopy, which has been suggested by other posters.

Comment: Please elaborate, the link might go stale leaving later visitors wondering if chasing all over the 'net is warranted.

Answer (score 0):

I use [XXCOPY](http://www.xxcopy.com/).

Comment: Had a quick look at xxcopy.com.   It is a MSDOS command line util !   As mentioned in my post, going back to MSDOS is just too slow (my temp workround wrapping all bigfiles in 7zip encapsulate. copy, unzip - if faster than MSDOS) Am I missing something ?

Comment: No, sorry I did not read your question properly and made my answer after looking at some of the other ones.  I use XXCOPY with scripts, so I just have to use the script name, the source and destination and one of a set of operation switches, so I do not have to remember all the switches and syntax.  Beats any GUI, for me.